# Creating a method to print an array

Tags: java

I am trying to find a way to print the contents of the array, while using a for loop. This is a fairly new section in java to me, as I am a beginner. Any help is appreciate in concerns to my question. My question is would I move the "Random" assessor method into the mutator method or am I just completely wrong and have to do something else.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayPractice {
private int[] arr;
private final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 300;
private final int MAX_VALUE = 100;

public ArrayPractice() {
// initialize array
arr = new int[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];

// randomly fill array with numbers
Random rand = new Random(1234567890);
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
  arr[i] = rand.nextInt(MAX_VALUE) + 1;
     }
  } 
public void printArray( ) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayPractice ap = new ArrayPractice();

System.out.println("The contents of my array are: ");
ap.printArray();
System.out.println("");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is would I move the "Random" assessor method into the
>   mutator method or am I just completely wrong and have to do something
>   else.

You don't have to. Just use a loop to iterate through the array which is already filled in the constructor.

```
public void printArray( ) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);    
    } 
}
```

By the way, with Java 8, you can write less lines of code to achieve the same result:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printArray() {

//Print array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

//another method with for loop 

 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
     {
       System.out.println(arr[i])
      }
}
```

Note there is plenty of other techniques

Answer (score 0):

In terms of writing clean code, it would probably be good to move this bit of code into its own private method within the class, and calling that within the constructor.

```
public ArrayPractice() {
    // initialize array
    arr = new int[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]; 
    populateArray();
}

private void populateArray() {
    // randomly fill array with numbers
    Random rand = new Random(1234567890);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
       arr[i] = rand.nextInt(MAX_VALUE) + 1;
    }
 }
```

Then in your printArray() method you can loop through the array and call System.out.println( ) for each item.

```
public void printArray( ) {
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
   }
}
```

If you come from a more functional background, I can show you how to write this more functionally using Java 8 lambdas. Let me know.